# ember-mocha: setupRenderingTest() stops tests from running

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mocha.js, ember-testing

I'm trying to setup some simple BDD tests for an ember project using `ember-mocha`. I've been following the [sample shown in the documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-mocha#setup-rendering-tests) however the callback that I pass to `it()` is never called:

```
import { render } from '@ember/test-helpers'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { setupRenderingTest } from 'ember-mocha'
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile'
import { describe, it } from 'mocha'

describe('UIButtonComponent', () => {

  // debugger // <-- breakpoint is hit if comment removed

  setupRenderingTest()

  it('renders text label', async () => {

    debugger // <-- breakpoint never hit

    await render(hbs`<UiButton @text={{ 'test' }} />`)

    expect(this.element.querySelector('img')).to.exist
  })
})
```

The callback passed to `describe()` is called, however my actual test never runs.

If I remove the call to `setupRenderingTest()`, then my test is executed (however it obviously fails).

Running the test produces this error in the web based test runner:

[image]

What could be causing the call to `setupRenderingTest()`, to stop my test from being run?

Comment: Could be the first arrow function since you are setting the context to undefined in this case

Comment: Thanks for the idea, tried both but neither worked

Comment: What version of ember-mocha do you have installed?

Comment: The latest - version 0.14.0